# Accessing a function from within a function in php?

Tags: php

How does scope work for functions in PHP? Can I use function A (defined outside function B) from within function B?

Comment: You could have made a simple test and find out by yourself...

Comment: You are right, but I had a problem with this in a website but the culprit was a different problem. Anyway even if its is an "easy"question, I am sure it will be useful for somebody googling it, so no need to be so whiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
function A()
{
  ...
}

function B()
{
  A();
}

B();
```

Answer (score 5):

From [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope - they can be called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice versa.

So **yes**, you can.

Answer (score 0):

[**Variable scope**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) if for variables.

There is no "scope" for functions... except when using namespaces.

Quoting the [**User-defined functions**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) section of the manual :

> All functions and classes in PHP have
>   the global scope - they can be called
>   outside a function even if they were
>   defined inside and vice versa.